# Duplicate entries being created on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, entity-framework

I'm hoping someone can help me out here, this has had me tearing my hair out for two days now.

I have a small system built using AngularJS, using an Entity Framework Code First project as a data layer. However, I'm having a bit of trouble getting the one to many relationship between ProjectDetails and ProjectTypes working correctly.

The ProjectTypes table contains 4 records (each a type of project), and each record in the ProjectDetails table should contain the ID of one of them as a foreign key. All very straight forward.

The code is compiling just fine, but it exhibits some strange behaviour when I run it, and I'm not sure if the problem lies with the EF mappings or my AngularJS code.

The AngularJS page is a form that allows the user to select a project type by means of a drop down list. The initial form submission is fine, and adds the correct project type. However, if I go back in and edit the form (selecting a new project type), it duplicates the currently selected project type in the ProjectType table and assigns the ID of the new type to the form submission.

I used the console.log in Chrome to have a look at the model when the edited form is submitted. The ProjectType_Id property (application.projectdetails.projecttype_id) has been correctly updated, but the ProjectType (application.projectdetails.projecttype) object has not.

I've included screenshots of what I think are the relevant parts of my project below. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Application**

The relevant model property for the overarching Application table.

```
public ProjectDetails ProjectDetails { get; set; }
```

**Project Details**

The relevant model properties for the 'Project Details' table (which is a 1-1 relationship with 'Applications'.

```
public Nullable<int> ProjectType_Id { get; set; }
public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
public virtual ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
```

**Project Type**

The relevant model property of the 'Project Type' table, which is a 1-many relationship with 'Project Details'.

```
public virtual ICollection<ProjectDetails> ProjectDetails { get; set; }
```

**Mapping**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
 .HasOptional(p => p.ProjectDetails)
 .WithOptionalPrincipal(o => o.Application)
 .Map(x => x.MapKey("Application_Id"));

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectDetails>()
 .HasOptional<ProjectType>(s => s.ProjectType)
 .WithMany(s => s.ProjectDetails)
 .HasForeignKey(s => s.ProjectType_Id);
```

**Angular Template**

This is the AngularJS code that is included in the SELECT drop down menu on the form. projecttypes is a $scope variable which is populated via a web service call.

Select menu tag:

```
ng-model="application.ProjectDetails.ProjectType_Id"
```

Select option tag:

```
ng-repeat="p in projecttypes" value="{{p.Id}}">{{p.ProjectName}}
```

**Backend Save Code:**

This doesn't directly update the form, rather it creates a new version of the application.

```
    public void UpdateApplication(Application existingItem)
    {
        if (existingItem == null)
            throw new ValidationException("An application is required.");

        if (existingItem.ParentApplication == 0)
        {
            existingItem.ParentApplication = existingItem.Id;
        }

        existingItem.Id = 0;
        existingItem.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
        existingItem.LatestVersion = true;
        existingItem.ApplicationGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        _context.Application.Add(existingItem);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the server-side code that saves the project.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code that saves the form. As stated, it doesn't update the form but instead creates a new version.

Comment: umm... why do `existingItem.ApplicationGuid = Guid.NewGuid();` if its updating? also, take note that ` _context.Application.Add(existingItem);` the `Add(object)` will insert new row if the `existingItem` is not tracked by current context. so, better to `attach` your `existingItem` to it first.. (it will use the primary key to do update - so primary key is mandatory).

Comment: Sorry, the name of the method is misleading. What the method is doing is creating a new record each time the form is submitted, rather than updating the original. It was a requirement by the customer.

Comment: Very common confusion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Thank you Gert, that was it exactly. I was referencing the navigation property as opposed to the foreign key. Working now!